# Selecting inner custom tags that have the same parent tag name

Tags: regex

I'm using regex to select custom tags, however some of these tags have inner tags of the same name.

My regex is getting mixed up.

```
\[STORE.*?\]((.*?|\n)*)\[\/STORE\]
```

Text:

```
[STORE SMC, DODO]blah blah blah blah blah
    [STORE SMC]blah[/STORE]
    [STORE DODO]Blah[/STORE].
[/STORE]

  ...some text here I do not want selected...

[STORE SMC]blah[/STORE]
```

Select the tags in another run or the same run?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
\[STORE[^\]]*]((.?|\n)*)\[\/STORE\]
```

Should work as expected: https://regex101.com/r/rkVKce/1

If you want to also get the inner tags you'll have to apply this regex recursivelly. I believe matching this is too much for pure regex.

Comment: Right, i should add that i have text in between some tags that I don't want to be selected. I have edited the original text. Thanks

Comment: Which text should not be selected?

Comment: The test I have marked as "Some text here I do not want selected." I have remormatted again so it is more clear. Sorry.

Comment: Oh, I get it now. What language are you using? This is not doable by regex.

Comment: Right, I'm using APEX, in Salesforce, its derived from Java. it uses pattern and matcher classes. I can make 2 calls if needed. I was guessing this was the way to go.

Comment: You could maybe try to use an xml parser. Just replace all `[` and `]` with `<` and `>` and it should work out of the box.